# Need to merge required js files in one js file

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, js

We are using a js library in our vf page by referencing the static resource where it is stored.
While upgrading to its latest version, the js file has many dependency on the required js files in its own lib folder. I need to merge all required js files into the main js file, so we can directly reference the main js file from static resource. I tried browserify and uglify using grunt but it gives 404 path error every time I tried to reference it.

Comment: Can you probably elaborate it a bit about what is precisely the problem? Where exactly do you receive a 404 error?

Comment: On updating the js file with higher version, I get 404 for that updated js file as well as other js files as well. I am updating jsZip library. Other files gives 404 due to I think this updated js file. The static resource is like one folder with all js files.

Comment: I would really advice to check the library docs about how to build it for web release. There is nothing different from that perspective between Static Resource and regular web app (source -- involved in development + building of few SPA based on VF using different libs)

Comment: Is there a way to remove all require references to lib js files and put all of them in one single parent js file.

Comment: There could be. Depends on library you use. Please check my previous comment